# Routing rule in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, routes

I have links such as: 
http://host.com/auto/contacts/?name=mercedes&page=2

I write rule to link: 
http://host.com/auto/contacts/?page=2

```
    [   'route' => 'auto/<action>',
        'pattern' => 'auto-<id:\d+>/<action:[-\w]+>/page-<page:\d+>',
    ],
```

But how to write rule, when I using 2 parametres (?name=mercedes&page=2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its similar like you write for one parameter:

```
'auto-<id:\d+>/<action:[-\w]+>/<name:\w+>/page-<page:\d+>'
```

But its limited to exactly that case when u have one parameter that will be 'name' and than 'page-x'. So if u will have later more parameters you will need to add new rule for matching them, or to create something more dynamic. I already explain in short how you can do with additional behavior when u have lot of categories and sub-categories [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24626220/209126)

You can do something similar with dynamic parameters also.

I hope this help you to get some idea.